# Angular doesn't trigger change detection on Array when passing to child componen

Tags: html, angular, typescript

I have a two dimensional array in my parent component and I'm trying to pass the inner arrays to the child component but it doesn't trigger the Angular change detection so it always shows an empty array.

Here is a shortened version of the .ts code of the parent component:

```
export class AssessmentResultComponent implements OnInit {
    assessmentResult: Rating[] = [];
    ratingCounts: number[][] = this.getRatingCount();

    constructor(private readonly assessmentResultService: AssessmentResultService, private readonly errorHandlingService: ErrorHandlingService, private readonly route: ActivatedRoute) {
}

    ngOnInit()
        :
        void {
                    this.assessmentResultService.getAssessmentResults(Number(this.route.snapshot.paramMap.get('id')))
.subscribe({
    next: (response) => {
        this.assessmentResult = response;
        this.ratingCounts = this.getRatingCount();
        console.log(this.ratingCounts)
    },
    error: (error) => this.errorHandlingService.handleError(error),
    });
}
}
```

Here is an example line of the HTML of the parent component and how I pass the inner array:

```
<app-bar-graph-multiple-choice [ratingCountData]="ratingCounts[0]"></app-bar-graph-multiple-choice>
```

And here is the child component .ts and how I want to use the data:

```
export class BarGraphMultipleChoiceComponent implements OnChanges{

  /*this doesn't update*/
  @Input() ratingCountData: number[] = [];

chartOptions = {
    data: [{
      type: "bar",
      dataPoints: [
        { label: this.label1,  y: this.ratingCountData[0]  },
        { label: this.label2, y: this.ratingCountData[1]  },
        { label: this.label3, y: this.ratingCountData[2]  },
        { label: this.label4,  y: this.ratingCountData[3]  },
        { label: this.label5,  y: this.ratingCountData[4]  }
      ]
    }]
  };

  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    /*if (changes['ratingCountData'].previousValue !== changes['ratingCountData'].currentValue) {
      this.ratingCountData = changes['ratingCountData'].currentValue;
      this.chartOptions.data[0].dataPoints[0].y = this.ratingCountData[0];
      this.chartOptions.data[0].dataPoints[1].y = this.ratingCountData[1];
      this.chartOptions.data[0].dataPoints[2].y = this.ratingCountData[2];
      this.chartOptions.data[0].dataPoints[3].y = this.ratingCountData[3];
      this.chartOptions.data[0].dataPoints[4].y = this.ratingCountData[4];
    }*/
    console.log(this.ratingCountData);
  }
}
```

Here is the getRatingCount() Method:

```
getRatingCount(): number[][] {
    let result: number[][] = new Array(5);
    for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
      result[i] = new Array(5);
    }

    for (let i = 0; i < result.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < result[i].length; j++) {
        result[i][j] = 0;
      }
    }

    this.assessmentResult.forEach(function (currentResult) {
      result[0][currentResult.zeitaufwandRating - 1]++;
      result[1][currentResult.inhaltRating - 1]++;
      result[2][currentResult.stoffmengeRating - 1]++;
      result[3][currentResult.niveauRating - 1]++;
      result[4][currentResult.relevanzRating - 1]++;
    });

    return result;
  }
```

I expect that the Angular change detection detects that the array has new content and that it shows on the page accordingly.

Comment: It doesn't detect change after rendering when logging changes['ratingCountData'].currentValue ?

Answer (score 0):

Without the code of your *getRatingCount* method, I can only assume that you add data to the **existing instance** of your matrix (ratingCounts). We have to keep in mind **what** the Change Detector in your Angular component is keeping track of: as far as you are working with a non-primitive value, the Change Detector will not be triggered until the **reference** to your object changes.

In fact, almost all of the Change Detectors in frameworks like Angular keep track of changes that happen in the **stack** zone of the RAM. Instead of pushing values in the matrix, you have to create the entire matrix from scratch. You can do this on your own, or using an Immutable-like library that, when you do something like (i.e.) a push, a brand new instance is returned.

By the way, if you could share the code placed in the *getRatingCount* method it would be great for further help.

Comment: Thanks so far! I added it to the question above :)

Answer (score 0):

Your ratingCount is updated from an observable so you have a couple options:

1. If you get your result as an observable you could use the async pipe in html:`[ratingCountData]="ratingCounts | async"`
2. You can run `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after you update it to trigger change detection manually
3. In case your subscription is outside the Angular zone, run the update in a zone   `this.zone.run(() => { this.ratingCounts = this.getRatingCount(); });`
4. If you're using something like `rxjs`, you could have ratingCountData as an `Subject` and push the new changes to it(with .next()) when they are available. You would then use the `async` pipe to subscribe to it in html.

[Here is a simple example of how the async pipe works.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-cm4rsl)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Could you show me where to put `this.cdr.detectChanges();` in the code? It's my first time dealing with Angular so I have no idea :)

Comment: You inject it in the component(for example in constructor you add `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef`) and then you call  `this.cdr.detectChanges();` after `this.ratingCounts = this.getRatingCount();`. But I suggest you also investigate the other solutions because calling the change detector manually is not something you want to do too much.

Comment: So I tried it like you said but it didn't work either. I also took a look at the async pipe but I ran into several issues. I'm still trying to figure that out :)